# How to get Google contacts without access token?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-contacts-api

**UPDATED**

I got my answer still with the help of `access token` :)

And going to mention it.

I am using `Google contacts API` to get `user` contacts.

I am using passport.js to login with Google and with help of `passport's access token` I am calling the `API`

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=999999&alt=json&oauth_token=' + token`

and getting the all the `contacts`

But I need to use something else instead of `access token` like `secret key`
 or `client key`.

Because every time I need to `log in` with `Google` for syncing the `contacts` if user added `newly contact`.

I did `Google` but didn't get any solution.

any idea will be helpful for me.

Here is my code to get Contacts

```
  var getGoogleContacts = function(token, userId) {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=999999&alt=json&oauth_token=' + token;
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                var contacts = JSON.parse(body);
                saveGoogleContacts(userId, contacts);
            }
        });

    };

    /*Get contacts and store in user_contact table*/
    var saveGoogleContacts = function(userId, contacts) {
        var gContacts = [];
        contacts.feed.entry.forEach(function(contact, index) {
            if (contacts.feed.entry[index].gd$email) {
                gContacts.push([
                    null, null, contacts.feed.entry[index].title.$t, "'" + contacts.feed.entry[index].gd$email[0].address + "'",
                    1, userId, 0
                ]);
            }
        });
        if (gContacts.length > 0) {
            user.insertContacts(gContacts, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('contacts saved: ' + result);
                }
            });
        }else{
            console.log('No records available');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. Do you want to sync contacts(newly added contacts) without using access token?

Comment: Yes, As Google API says that the `access token` will expire after `one hr`  and I am  maintaining my local session `one month` for application, so I don't need to log in again before one month, so I need a different approach to get newly contacts if user added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here I got my answer.**

As I mentioned I am using `passport.js` to log in with `Google`

And during log in process `passport` provides `access token` and `refresh token` by default `refresh token` will be `null`.

If you want to get `refresh token` you need to pass `parameter` `accessType:offline` during authentication process, Like this

`app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email','https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'],accessType: 'offline', approvalPrompt: 'force' }));`

After that you'll get `refresh token` and store it in any permanent place since it will not be `expire` and can use whenever you want to get `access token`

To get `access token` I am using [**refresh-token**](https://github.com/jfromaniello/refresh-token)  module.

After gertting `token` just need to call the `API` to get contacts.

Like this

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=999999&alt=json&oauth_token=' + token;
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                cb(error);
            } else {
                var contacts = JSON.parse(body);
                cb(null, contacts);
            }
        });
    }
```

That's it.